# Change WordPress header color using customizer

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, theme-options

I have theme customize function in my customizer.php file:

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport         = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogdescription' )->transport  = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'header_textcolor' )->transport = 'postMessage';
}
```

But I can't change header_textcolor using theme customizer. How can I use header text color value in my theme?

My header css:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
    color: #777;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to inline the css into your theme. CSS is read-only and can't updated to use the update hex colors for your header.

`<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor' );?> 100%);">`

So find the `div` in your theme called `navbar-default` and update it to this:

`<div style="background:#<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor' );?>"> class="navbar-default">`